# Android 4.3.X Notification Listener

Tags: android, notifications, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I am trying to create an App that uses the new Android service to read all notifications and also remove them, but it is not working.
In the Manifest I have:

```
<service android:name="com.tortuga.shutapp.NotificationListener"
     android:label="@string/app_name"
     android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

I have a class NotificationListener that extends NotificationListenerService
I override the two methods onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn),     onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn).

I have given it permission under Security->Notification Access...
But I still can't read any notification that pops.
What seems to be the problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android caches the binder returned from onBind so if your actions are very similar and your app binds first, then your binder will be returned to the system one instead of the system binder (returned from `super.onBind(intent)`

Luckily, Android keys the binder cache based on the intent action. I would give your intent some dummy action so that it doesn't get mixed with the system one. I've solved the same problem by doing this. NOTE: categories are not sufficient.

Comment: So you are telling me that, because my code doesn't do anything special (for now) then Android just omit it?

Comment: Sorry, I misread that you had also overridden onBind.

Try toggling the permission. If your notification listener service ever crashes, Android is really bad at restarting it and sending it notifications. Toggling the permission (or restarting your phone) are the only ways I've found to get Android to rebind to it.

Comment: Hi! You were not mistaken, I overrided the onBind, but then I saw it is not necessary..
By "Toggling the permission" do you mean to unset it? in the code or in the Security->Notification Access..?
Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, uncheck and check again. Also try checking logcat when a notification comes in. I test notifications by sending myself a hangout message from one of my secondary accounts.

Comment: This was super useful, and the only answer i managed to find online, thank you!

Comment: @Gabe toggling notification access permission didn't work for me but a simple restart did it ! thanks

Answer (score 0):

make sure you gave the app notification listen permission, toggle it again will recreate the service